# Server Based Databases

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need some help and advice before starting a personal project of mine. I want to develop a iOS app that connects to a server based mySQL database or something equivalent that allows me to pull information from that database to a TableView and then add, edit, and remove that information and it updates on the server so I can always access the latest information. I was wondering if anyone would have any tips, tutorials or how-to on starting something like this. Even if the tutorials are something even simpler it would be a great starting point. Thanks.

Comment: One way to achieve this is to create a local server using socket.io/node.js in javascript. The you can connect to the port that the server is listening on, which when connected, the server would return data, in your case it will be data from your database. Google socket.io and node.js

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

Following is one of them, which is according to me easy & efficient way.

1. Create local database
2. In AppDelegate check whether your local storage (tables in databse) is empty
3. Now there are two possibilities

   1. yes -> Fetch data from web server
   2. no -> Fetch data from local database
4. If you go through 3.1, then store fetched web server data into local database along with extra variable say **counter as 0**
5. Fetch data from the local database along with its counter value. For now say **counter = 0**. This counter variable should also exist at server side.

   1. When there is any update occur on server side; value for this counter variable will increment.
6. display data as per your need
7. Add some click event which check for the latest updates
8. This event will fetch counter variable from server side.
9. compare this counter value with already stored counter value at your local database.
10. Now again there are two possibilities

    1. If counter value at server > counter value at local database  -------> follow & repeats steps from **step 4**.
    2. If counter value at server <= counter value at local database  ----> Your local database is stored with latest updates

Enjoy Programming!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to start a ios web services with a core data, have a look at this:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/17927/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-2